# Using Row Number to Partition data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

Okay this is one of those situations where I have concluded that I am lost.

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I have written the following code:

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
 USER_NBR
,CASE WHEN MOVIE_TYPE = 'Action'      THEN MOVIE_NAME END [ACTION]                        
,CASE WHEN MOVIE_TYPE = 'Drama'       THEN MOVIE_NAME END DRAMA
,CASE WHEN MOVIE_TYPE = 'Romance'     THEN MOVIE_NAME END ROMANCE
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  USER_NBR ORDER BY  USER_NBR) AS OCCURANCE
FROM dbo.MOVIE)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE OCCURANCE = 1
```

I get this result:

[image]

What I don't understand is why am I getting Nulls in the query result?

What am I doing wrong? As you can see I am categorizing the movies.

Thanks for checking this out

Comment: What value are you expecting in the `NULL`-valued columns?

Comment: Pretty Woman and Love Actually. The two movies that are in that category. Thanks!

Comment: So you're trying to display the "first" (although there's no clear definition of order in your query) `movie` of each type by `user_nbr` on a single row?

Comment: Remove condition `occurance = 1` for more clear picture ... 
see you have case condition on same column value ... if movie_type <> Drama then your output query will not have value in DRAMA column . .

Comment: You're actually meaning to do a pivot then...

Comment: I would like to display or get one line per USER. So I was using the OCCURANCE as a way to limit the result to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this approach will work for you.  In general when you're turning row values into columns (like movie types in your example), it's a pivot function (ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

```
select * from 
(select user_nbr, movie_name, movie_type from movies) as movies
pivot 
(max(movie_name)
    for movie_type in ([Action], [Drama], [Romance])
)
as PivotTable
```

Result:

```
user_nbr   Action             Drama           Romance
101        Casino Royale    Pretty Woman    Love Actually
102        Casino Royale    Pretty Woman    Love Actually
```

Comment: This also works perfectly: So how would I insert this into a new table with an actual Action, Drama and Romance column?

Comment: @UnaverageGuy, you could do this:  INSERT INTO new_table (user_nbr, action, drama, romance) SELECT * FROM (...)

Answer (score 0):

please note that if you are trying to get this type of output the you have to use group by clause ..

say if you want to get value for all the category then you can try following query ..

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
 USER_NBR
,CASE WHEN MOVIE_TYPE = 'Action'      THEN MOVIE_NAME END [ACTION]                        
,CASE WHEN MOVIE_TYPE = 'Drama'       THEN MOVIE_NAME END DRAMA
,CASE WHEN MOVIE_TYPE = 'Romance'     THEN MOVIE_NAME END ROMANCE
,count(*) AS OCCURANCE
FROM dbo.MOVIE
 group by USER_NBR
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

I think this is what you are trying to do ..

Comment: The code you indicated does not show a single row but all the data, not what I am intending but thank you!

Comment: SOLVED! All I needed to do was add MAX to each CASE and a GROUP BY USER_NBR in the CTE block. No More Nulls!! Thanks everyone!